# Why are output nets also required to be redeclared as either 'wire' or 'reg'?

Tags: verilog

Why do we have to take the same variable name of an output and also wire for getting the value? eg:

```
 module TEST(INP1,INP2,CIN,COUT,SUM);
 input [31:0] INP1;
 input [31:0] INP2;
 output [31:0] SUM;
 input CIN;
 output COUT;

 wire [31:0] SUM;// Again redefined 
 wire COUT; // Again Redefined
 assign {COUT,SUM} = INP1 + INP2 + CIN ;
```

Example for getting the Carry-out and the Sum of two numbers and Carry-In taken as the input.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Verilog 1995** did require the port direction to be listed after. Output wire types were implicit and regs could be declared inline with direction.

```
module TEST(A,B,C,D);
  input  [31:0] A;
  input  [31:0] B;
  output [31:0] C;
  output        D;

  reg D;
```

could be written as:

```
module TEST(A,B,C,D);
  input      [31:0] A;
  input      [31:0] B;
  output     [31:0] C;
  output reg        D; //Only declared twice
```

Since **Verilog 2001** the extra definition is no longer required and they can be declared inline (ANSI-Style).

```
module TEST(
  input      [31:0] A,
  input      [31:0] B,
  output     [31:0] C,
  output reg        D  // Declared Once
);
```

From **SystemVerilog** (2009) we have the logic type, you no longer have to switch between reg and wire types. The only requirement is that if you need to tri-state use wire or tri.

```
module TEST(
  input        [31:0] A,
  input        [31:0] B,
  output logic [31:0] C,
  output logic        D
);
```

My understanding of the original requirement for having reg and wire types was for simulation speed or ease of simulator design. The value of a wire is evaluated every simulation delta cycle while a reg is only evaluated when triggered by the sensitivity list.

Answer (score 4):

It is not necessary to declare an `output` also as a `wire`.  Furthermore, you can avoid duplicating the port list by using ANSI-stlye port declarations:

```
module TEST (
    input [31:0] INP1,
    input [31:0] INP2,
    output [31:0] SUM,
    input CIN,
    output COUT
);

    assign {COUT,SUM} = INP1 + INP2 + CIN ;
endmodule
```

In your example, you do not need to declare outputs as `reg`.  But, if you need to for another circuit, you can declare the type on the same line, such as:

```
output reg [31:0] Q;
```

Answer (score -1):

Because just declaring a net as `output` doesn't describe if it is a `reg` type or a `wire` type.

An output can either be driven by a wire or reg, you have to tell it what type the driver is going to be.